# Capacitor/Android Question: How to obtain current Context?

Tags: java, android, capacitor-plugin

I am developing a Capacitor (4) plugin and need to access Android system services, which requires referencing the current `Context`. How do I obtain the context within the scope of the plugin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call `this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in a class that extends `com.getcapacitor.Plugin`.

For example, see below custom plugin code:

```
package com.example.mypackage;

import com.getcapacitor.JSObject;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod;
import com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin;

@CapacitorPlugin(name = "MyPackage")
public class MyPackagePlugin extends Plugin {

    private MyPackage implementation = new MyPackage(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    @PluginMethod
    public void echo(PluginCall call) {
        String value = call.getString("value");

        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        ret.put("value", implementation.echo(value));
        call.resolve(ret);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the more recent versions of `Capacitor` you can also call the `getContext` method which is defined in the built-in `Plugin.java` file.

```
/**
 * Get the main {@link Context} for the current Activity (your app)
 * @return the Context for the current activity
 */
public Context getContext() {
    return this.bridge.getContext();
}
```

Reference link: [Plugin source](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/main/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/Plugin.java)

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is surprisingly absent from the Android documentation for Capacitor. It's so fundamental to successfully packaging native functionality into a plugin. Thank you!